# How do I properly use the MEMBER OF function in Oracle 11g

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following code and every time I executes it, I get the error PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MEMBER OF'. Can anyone please tell me how I am using this function incorrectly? If not what is the proper way to use it?

If I am using this correctly, how else can I inspect the contents of the array?

```
DECLARE
    TYPE type_cd IS VARRAY(12) OF CHAR(2);
    v_my_list  type_cd ;
    v_cd    CHAR(2) := 'AA';
BEGIN
    v_my_list   := type_cd (v_cd);

    IF v_cd MEMBER OF v_my_list
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is a member of v_my_list');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is NOT a member of v_my_list');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Oracle's [Support for Collection Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjcol.htm) page:

> The **`MEMBER [OF]`** or **`NOT MEMBER [OF]`** condition tests whether an element is a member of a nested table, returning the result as a Boolean value.

The `MEMBER` comparison works on nested tables not `VARRAY`s.

Change `VARRAY(12)` for `TABLE` and it will work:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE type_cd IS TABLE OF CHAR(2);
    v_my_list  type_cd ;
    v_cd    CHAR(2) := 'AA';
BEGIN
    v_my_list   := type_cd (v_cd);

    IF v_cd MEMBER OF v_my_list
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is a member of v_my_list');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is NOT a member of v_my_list');
    END IF;
END;
```

**Edit**:

You can use a simple loop to check if a member exists in a `VARRAY`:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE type_cd IS VARRAY(12) OF CHAR(2);
    v_my_list  type_cd ;
    v_cd    CHAR(2) := 'AA';
    v_found BOOLEAN := false;
    v_index INTEGER;
BEGIN
    v_my_list   := type_cd (v_cd);

    v_index := v_my_list.FIRST;
    WHILE NOT v_found AND v_index IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF v_my_list(v_index) = v_cd THEN
        v_found := true;
      ELSE
        v_index := v_my_list.NEXT( v_index );
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF v_found THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is a member of v_my_list at ' || v_index );
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cd || ' is NOT a member of v_my_list');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I should have known that :) Is there any way to inspect the content of a VARRAY in a similar fashion though?

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense, I was hoping that there would be a pre-defined function. Obviously looping through the array and searching for your value will give you the results you want. I was just trying to avoid that :)